# Receive SMS Messages only when Activity in Running

Tags: android, crash, sms, manifest

I am building an Android application that receives SMS messages and displays them from a particular gateway/sender.

The problem is, if I declare the receiver in the AndroidManifest file, it keeps receiving messages from everyone and at all times, even when the app is paused/closed. This causes a force crash of the app every time I receive a SMS message when not on the app.

This is my code in ReceieveMessage.java

```
package com.phoenix.omnisurf;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class ReceiveMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
public static String messageBody = "";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {

        messageBody = "";

        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage messageHandler = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            messageBody += messageHandler.getDisplayMessageBody();
        }

        SurfActivity.mThis.messageContainer.setText(messageBody);
    }
}
}
```

I also have the following receiver registered on my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <!-- Message Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiveMessage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

How do I create a Broadcast Receiver that is on only when the particular activity is open or when the app is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check whether your Activity is in foreground or not

Add this to your Activity
    private static boolean isInForeground;

```
onResume(){
 super.onResume();
 isInForground = true;
}

onPause(){
 super.onPause();
 isInForground = false;
}
```

And in your Receiver class check like

```
 if(SurfActivity.isInForeground){
   SurfActivity.mThis.messageContainer.setText(messageBody);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, maybe because I'm learning while developing... Could you please expand? I've added my code in the question so that it'll be easier to understand.

Comment: @AmruthA.Pillai dont take views as static in Activity

Comment: Is this what you mean? I am getting some errors in the code though, saying, there is no onStart method in super. http://paste.ofcode.org/32ugYVYWBNXgqVQepVRfPy6

Comment: @AmruthA.Pillai its in receiver..you have to use it in Activity

Comment: first check this http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.in/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html

Comment: I changed the `extends BroadcastReceiver` to `Activity`, but the message still doesn't show up on the app, like how I have defined in onReceive().

Comment: just add this code in  SurfActivity class..dont change classes whatever you like..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71081/discussion-between-amruth-a-pillai-and-kalyan-pvs).

Answer (score 2):

You can register your receiver dynamically:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}
```